# Should this sentence be split in two, or is my use of "all of which" grammatically correct?

Tags: relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses, run-on-sentences

Just wondering if my sentence is too long, confusing, or grammatically incorrect!

I completed two primary school placements in opposite socioeconomic areas as well as volunteer in two youth clubs, **all of which** occurred while I worked a part-time job and completed my school work.

Your knowledge and wisdom would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Volunteer should be volunteered if it's not still ongoing.

Comment: I think it will be "volunteered" instead of "volunteer". Like it is a completed task I am guessing.

Comment: The rest of the sentence looks completely fine.

Comment: I might suggest "I've completed two primary school placements in opposite socioeconomic areas and volunteer in two youth clubs, all while working a part-time job and completing my school work."  Your sentence is fine, but resume writing like this can get clunky if you don't cut as many words as possible.  The reader has a lot of them to read, get your main points across fast.  Just my opinion from a lot of cover letters.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone! 

CaptainSkyfish, this is part of a personal statement for a university application. Do you think it's still necessary to cut as many words out as possible?